# Java read one text input with multiple newline characters

Tags: java

I'm looking for a way to read a line that is copied and pasted into an IDE or a terminal/cmd, such that a BufferedReader will read all of the text even when it encounters a newline character ('\n). The tricky part is that the reader will have to know that the user has pressed enter (which is a newline), but it has to keep reading all of the characters in the input string until it has reached the last `'\n'`.

Is there any way to do this (such as with an InputStreamReader or something)?

ANSWER:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    int ch;

    System.out.println("Paste text below (enter or append to text \"ALT + 1\" to exit):");

    try {
        while ((ch = reader.read()) != (char)63 /*(char)63 could just be ☺*/) {
            sb.append(ch);
        }
        reader.close();
    }catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e.toString());
    }
    String in = sb.toString();
    System.out.println(in);
}
```

Comment: If I have a hundred newlines in my paste buffer, then I hit Enter, which newline one do I accept as the "last" newline?

Comment: No, this is not possible.

Comment: That is truly upsetting. I was thinking that perhaps I could tell the user to copy and paste to a text file and then use BufferedReader's readLine(), but that just seems weird. I can get as far as pasting the text into Netbeans's terminal, but the BufferedReader just won't read past the second line. Is everyone sure that you cannot change the BufferedReader's target char (meaning if it reads a particular char - such as \n in the default case - and then terminates reading)? It doesn't sound like it, but I just want to make sure.

Comment: I just did it with InputStreamReader... I didn't think that would work. I get a bunch of boxes (null char... '\u0000') afterwards, but it worked. I essentially just created an array of chars with 10000 indexes. Then, I entered text with a bunch of new lines (using inputStreamReader_object.read(charArray))... AND IT WORKED!

Comment: "One line with multiple newline characters" is a contradiction in terms.

Comment: Changed... it's true, though. I enter one line with a bunch of newline characters (although you cannot see them), and then I tried to use BufferedReader on 'em, and it didn't work because BufferedReader looks for newline chars.

Comment: Then it isn't really one line.  There's nothing magical about the end of the "line" you're inputting; a newline character *is* the end of a line.  What I'm trying to get you to see is that what you're interested in doing is *not* read to the end of the line, but read to the end of the input.

Comment: Indeed; that so happens to be the case, and apparently there is no way to do that except read a bunch of chars until you hit a null char - which brings me to another question: what if there is a null char in the text. I could keep reading to see if there are 100 or so concurrent null chars I guess, but it raises a fair point that you can't really just look for a null char.

Comment: If you're pasting into a terminal, the terminal might treat the first newline as the end of input and try to interpret the rest as commands.  Depending on the shell, you'd have to use something like a "here document" to pass the whole input to the Java program.

Comment: Hm, that's a good point; thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see you've made an effort, so I'll show you what I mean.  This is a pretty common pattern when you need to read from a stream:

```
char[] buffer = new char[1000];
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
int count;
// note this loop condition
while((count = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    sb.append(buffer, 0, count);
}
String input = sb.toString();
```

Comment: Thanks; I tried it out, and it gets stuck somewhere. I ran a for loop inside the while loop to print out all of the chars in the buffer, and -- apparently -- the chars in the input stream reader reads partial texts twice (both from the beginning) and gets stuck in some loop like before. I also simply did a while (true){}` and inside that did `count = reader.read(buffer); if (count = -1) break; else Sys..println(count);` and it print 28 and did not continue. How is it not continuing?

Comment: I got it to read everything and only print it out once if I have a print statement within the while reader.read() != -1 loop, but then it STILL GETS STUCK AT THE END. I cannot figure out why.

Comment: I'm having trouble following what you're saying.  Post your revised code?

Comment: The problem was that the inputstreamreader was waiting for something to say to it "hey, you're closed" or "hey, there's no more input coming from this; you should close", and since it thought there would be more input, it kept waiting for something. So, I solved that by having the user (hopefully they'll - it will really just be me using it - be using windows) input a smiley at the end (ALT + 1) and then pressing enter. This terminates the loop. The revised code is above in my answer part.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I didn't see this on Stack Overflow, so I thought I would ask, and I didn't know if InputStreamReader would work... but I guess it does. So, if you ever want to read text that has a bunch of newline characters, you have to use `InputStreamReader`.

This is a class implements [`Reader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html) (which implements `readable` and `closeable` and has a method (`read(chBuf)`) that allows you to read an input stream to the buffer characters (an array), chBuf. The code that I used to test this is as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String in = "";

    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);

    System.out.println("paste text with multiple newline characters below:");

    try {
        char chs[] = new char[1000];
        int n;
        while (reader.read(chs) != -1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < chs.length; i++) {
                char ch = chs[i];
                if (ch == '\u0000') {
                    break;
                } 
                in += chs[i];
            }
            System.out.println(in);
        }
        System.out.print(".");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e.toString());
    }

    System.out.println(in);
}
```

This works... sort of. It prints the inputted text one and a half times.

Comment: Ok, it worked a bunch of times in succession, but it isn't working very well now. It cannot even read the entire thing. I got rid of the `if (chs[i] == '\u0000') { break; }`, and it appears as though at a certain point all of the chars after a random index are converted to null chars... I have no idea why.

Comment: `InputStreamReader` implements `Reader`.  It does not extend `InputStream`.  You're running into problems because `read(char[])` is not guaranteed to read all available input.  Your should call it in a loop until it returns -1.  The array elements that are null haven't been converted to null; they were just never set to anything else because the reader didn't read that far into your input.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by doing it in a loop. This just seems to fill up the char buffer from the beginning of the inputted text and print half the input multiple times.